# Problems using URL Rewrite in IIS7 for friendly URLs

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm trying to make some rewrite rules in my IIS7 server using URL Rewrite. 
For example, I have the url mydomain.com/data.php?id=1 and I want to convert it to mydomain.com/archive/1

Currently I have:

```
    <rule name="Ugly to friendly" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^data\.php$" />
  <conditions>
      <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
      <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^([^=&amp;]+)=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="archive/{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" /> 
</rule>

<rule name="Friendly to ugly" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="archive/(.+)" />
  <conditions>
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="data.php?id={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

but it doesn't work (read as "page shows fine without that rule, but when rule is added no css/imgs are shown).
Weird, as firebug tells me that everything is ok (200 OK) (maybe it gets confused too?)

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the code is just fine. My page (data.php) is wrong. Instead of having all imgs/css using relative paths from the php file, I should have wrote those using relative paths from the root.

I mean, instead of "img src="../../test.jpg" I should have wrote "img src="/folder1/fol".

Note the "/" at the beggining of the path.